# Entity Framework Code First very long queries to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am learning EF Code First approach and i have problem with very long queries.

I have this DB classes:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the INSERT query:

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
        {                
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a name for a new Blog: ");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();

            var blog = new Blog { Name = name };
            db.Blogs.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

This query spends 3+ seconds for add one row! Adding producing in SQL Server Express LocalDb. I changed it and now add data in SQL Server Compact, but nothing happened! Very long time of adding query!

When i used Database First and Model First approaches all was allright, fast.

What is the problem with code first?

Comment: How much time does it take to add a second row? After the first `SaveChanges()`, create a new Blog, add it and save it.

Comment: momental, i forgot that the first query is long. Thanks!